# Can I set a custom ui-widget-overlay class when opening a jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

The jQuery UI dialog has a `dialogClass` option, which is nice, since the dialog is nested directly within the document `<body>`. However when setting the `modal` option to `true`, a ui-widget-overlay div is also rendered directly within the body (as a sibling of the dialog div).

Is there a way to, in effect, apply an `overlayClass` when opening a jQuery UI dialog with `modal: true`?

I know we could apply custom css to the overlay by giving the `<body>` a class attribute, or by overriding the .ui-widget-overlay class directly. I'm looking for a solution that would make a css definition like the following work:

```
.my-custom-class.ui-widget-overlay {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set JQuery UI modal dialog overlay background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583995/set-jquery-ui-modal-dialog-overlay-background-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option for this.  Looking at the source, there's not an easy way to jocky it in there either.  For reference, here's the bit that adds the class:

```
    var $el = (this.oldInstances.pop() || $('<div></div>').addClass('ui-widget-overlay'))
        .appendTo(document.body)
        .css({
            width: this.width(),
            height: this.height()
        });
```

You likely would be best to just customize / update your css to override / extend the default stylings.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a really simple way to do this using the CSS.(So long as you downloaded the jQuery UI library). There should be a jquery style sheet entitled: "jqGrid-custom.css"

Simply go into the overlays section and adjust this line:

```
.ui-widget-overlay { background: #aaaaaa url(/img/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity:.9;filter:Alpha(Opacity=90); }
```