# jQuery: Set modal dialog overlay color

Tags: overlay, jquery-ui-dialog

I would like to pop a modal dialog using jquery ui where the overlay is completely black. I know that I can set this in the theme, but I do not want all dialogs to have a black overlay. Just one of them.

Is there a way to configure a dialog's background (overlay) color on a per-dialog basis? Perhaps when it is created?

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Darker background in Jquery UI dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583995/darker-background-in-jquery-ui-dialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frederic's answer was very close but it left me with one problem: I had more than one dialog on that page, and after I changed the overlay for the one dialog, it changed all of them until the page was reloaded. However, it did give me an idea;

First I stored the default values into variables (page scope), and then set my custom style.

```
var overlay = $(".ui-widget-overlay");
baseBackground = overlay.css("background");
baseOpacity = overlay.css("opacity");
overlay.css("background", "#000").css("opacity", "1");
```

Then when the dialog is closed, I restored those values.

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").css("background", baseBackground).css("opacity", baseOpacity);
```

The main reason for storing them in variables (as opposed to resetting them to explicit values) is for maintainability. This way, even if the site.css changes, it will work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So the overlay element is reused for all dialog widgets... good catch :)

Comment: This same mechanic can be accomplished by adding and removing a css class that sets these values (which is what I ultimately ended up implementing).

Answer (score 45):

You can use the **open** and **close** events of the ui-dialog.

```
$("#your-dialog").dialog(
{
    autoOpen: false, 
    modal: true, 
    open: function() {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('custom-overlay');
    }          
});
```

And add the required styling in the CSS. Example:

```
.ui-widget-overlay.custom-overlay
{
    background-color: black;
    background-image: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 1040;    
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the "z-index: 1040" places the overlay on top of the dialog. Remove z-index and it works fine.

Comment: One small improvement, selector `$('.ui-widget-overlay')` will find all overlays for all opened dialogs. You can extend jQuery UI with a new method for getting the overlay for your particular dialog

Comment: like this `$.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    getOverlay: function() {
        return (this.overlay) ? this.overlay.$el : $();
    }
});` and calling `$("#your-dialog").dialog('getOverlay')` than to do what you want.

Answer (score 12):

The overlay element is an immediate sibling of the dialog widget and exposes the `ui-widget-overlay` class, so you can match it and modify the background color on a per-dialog basis:

```
$("#yourDialog").dialog("widget")
                .next(".ui-widget-overlay")
                .css("background", "#f00ba2");
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBBLh/).

Comment: Hmmm when I do this my overlay appears at the bottom of the page extending the page height, rather than behind my original dialog

Comment: Actually this is happening to me doing it via CSS as well so there is nothing wrong with the JavaScript above.

Answer (score 11):

The background of the JQuery dialog is a div that has the class "ui-widget-overlay". The key styles you want to adjust is "opacity", "filter" and "background-color" ("opacity" and "filter" are two different ways of setting opacity for the different browsers.) You can either adjust the class definition or do the following in the dialog definition:

```
$("div#MyDialog").dialog({
    title: "My Dialog Title",
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").css({
            opacity: 1.0,
            filter: "Alpha(Opacity=100)",
            backgroundColor: "black"
        });
    },
    modal: true
});
```

Comment: How does JQ UI use an image for their overlay?

Answer (score 3):

Change background:

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").css({background: "#000", opacity: 0.9});
```

Restore background to CSS values:

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").css({background: '', opacity: ''});
```

Comment: Simpler Solution. Thanks!