# creating a blurred background effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a blur effect on a page. I want a popup to show, and then the rest of the page be blurred. However I only seem to be able to blur background images, not actual elements on the page, is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blur effect on a div element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977103/blur-effect-on-a-div-element)

Comment: Modern browsers only - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use CSS (and JavaScript?) to create a blurred, "frosted" background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092299/how-to-use-css-and-javascript-to-create-a-blurred-frosted-background)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268593/jquery-set-modal-dialog-overlay-color

Comment: Try: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/blurred/

Answer (score 5):

You can blur individual elements, but you can't create a blurring overlay.

Fortunately, the CSS `-prefix-filter: blur(##)` automatically applies to child elements. What you'd need to is wrap every element *except* your popup in a div, then [apply the blur to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034485/ios-7s-blurred-overlay-effect-using-css).

Example JS:

```
$('body > *').wrap('<div class="blur-all">').append($popup);
```

CSS:

```
.blur-all {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Don't forget to unwrap the children of `.blur-all` once you're done with the popup.